# Given two lists in python one with strings and one with objects, how do you map them?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings

```
string_list = ["key_val_1", "key_val_2", "key_val_3", "key_val_4", ...]
```

and a list with objects

```
object_list = [object_1, object_2, object_3,...]
```

Every object `object_i` has an attribute `key`.

I want to **sort the objects in `object_list` by the order of `string_list`**.

I could do something like

```
new_list = []
for key in string_list:    
    for object in object_list:
        if object.key == key:
            new_list.append(object)
```

but there must be a more pythonic way, then this brute force one. :-) How would you solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create a dictionary mapping object keys to objects:

```
d = dict((x.key, x) for x in object_list)
```

Next create the sorted list using a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [d[key] for key in string_list]
```

Comment: +1 but don't forget to include the logic that perhaps the `string_list` contains a string whose `key` is not within your dictionary.

Comment: @wheaties: Not sure if this is needed.  If so, simply replace `d[key]` by `d.get(key)` to insert `None` whenever a key is unmatched.

Answer (score 2):

Map each key to its desired precedence:

```
key_precedence = dict((x, n) for n, x in enumerate(string_list))
```

Then sort by precedence:

```
object_list.sort(key=lambda x: key_precedence[x.key])
```

To handle keys that might not be in string_list:

```
default = -1          # put "unknown" in front
default = sys.maxint  # put "unknown" in back
object_list.sort(key=lambda x: key_precedence.get(x.key, default))
```

If string_list is short (e.g. 10 or fewer items), you can simplify:

```
object_list.sort(key=lambda x: string_list.index(x.key))
# But it's more cumbersome to handle defaults this way.
```

However, this is prohibitive for larger lengths of string_list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cmp argument of the sort() method:

```
object_list.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(string_list.index(x.key),
                                     string_list.index(y.key)))
```

or use sorted() to avoid the in-place substitution:

```
sorted(object_list, cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(string_list.index(x.key),
                                        string_list.index(y.key)))
```